# ranger not opening pdf files?

Tags: pdf, ranger

My pdf reader is mupdf. It works and is on my PATH. My `rifle.conf` is (relevant part):

```
#-------------------------------------------                                    
# Documents                                                                     
#-------------------------------------------                                    
ext pdf, has mupdf,    X, flag f = mupdf -- "$@"                                
ext pdf, has zathura,  X, flag f = zathura -- "$@"                              
ext pdf, has llpp,     X, flag f = llpp "$@"                                    
ext pdf, has apvlv,    X, flag f = apvlv -- "$@"                                
ext pdf, has xpdf,     X, flag f = xpdf -- "$@"                                 
ext pdf, has evince,   X, flag f = evince -- "$@"                               
ext pdf, has okular,   X, flag f = okular -- "$@"                               
ext pdf, has epdfview, X, flag f = epdfview -- "$@
```

I ran `--copy-config=all` and made sure the config file in my home dir was configured as above. I also used `locate` to search for any other config files and configured them as aforementioned too. I tried running ranger with `-d` (debug) but it did not provide any useful info for debugging this issue. Ranger used to work with zathura IIRC, and it works with other document types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if you still need this answered, but I had this exact issue and I fixed it by removing the "--" after "mupdf" (so it's in the same form as the line for llpp). This might be system-specific because it works fine on another computer (with a different distro) where the config has the "--".

Comment: That was it, thank you. It seems that this has been fixed in the most recent version ([here](https://github.com/hut/ranger/blob/master/ranger/config/rifle.conf)).

Comment: The same applies for `zathura`, or at least if you have the `mupdf` backend for `zathura`.

Comment: Removing the `--`  also works for this error `xdg-open: unexpected option '--'` .

Comment: is it possible to share your scope.sh for pdf ?